# d3 - force diagram where a moving node is the center of gravity

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

Currently I have a force diagram where the center of the diagram is where every node gravitates to. See this diagram:
[image]

What I'm trying to do is make it so all of the orange nodes have a pull towards themselves, and all the smaller nodes congregate around the closest orange node. It's similar to [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/donaldh/2920551) except I do not want fixed points, as orange nodes can move around. It also seems that in the fixed point example, nodes are drawn to where they are because of their index; I want them to be drawn by a force.

My current code for generating this force is this:

```
 force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge (d) -> if isMassive d then d.size*100 else d.size
    .chargeDistance (d) -> d.size*10
    .gravity 0.01
    .friction 0.01
    .size [Constants.width, Constants.height]
    .on "tick", tick
```

(for reference, orange nodes pass the isMassive check)

I've tried giving orange nodes a negative charge, as well as giving the smaller nodes a negative charge, both while their opposite was positive. I've also tried any number of gravity / friction / etc combinations (ranging from 0 to 1 to a few numbers inbetween). I'd also like to add that I have *no* links in this system.

Comment: Set `gravity` to 0 and the charge of the orange nodes to a large value. You do need the links between the nodes that you want to interact with each other, but you don't need to draw them.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I was hoping to not have links at all, since that would mean there is always one "parent" node. I was hoping to make it more of a loose association such that smaller nodes would just be attracted to the larger ones. I take it that isn't possible?

Comment: It sounds like you would need the links.

Comment: So is there a way to automatically link a node up with a nearby node that is larger? Obviously d3 won't support this but I don't know the best way to handle this.

Comment: You could simply link everything to everything else.

Comment: That's an interesting way of doing it. I'll give that a try.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Does it make sense to link something to itself? Is there any adverse consequence of doing so?

Comment: That won't have any effect I think.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any really easy way to do this with fixed nodes: http://puu.sh/bz8T7/cb40ee2b1a.jpg The nodes that aren't orange just seem to go to the center, not really moving towards any particular orange node. I've tried many combinations of chargeDistance, linkDistance, and linkStrength coupled with your charge suggestion. Would it help if I made a demo to show you better?

Comment: Yes, it would help if you could post the code for the picture.

Comment: Here's my code: http://plnkr.co/edit/Lux1rB1VPdITYdAURQTi?p=preview - I added a few notes to the script file.

Comment: Ah right, if you link all the grey nodes to all the orange nodes, they will end up in the middle. Maybe a [multi-foci force layout](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1021953) is more along the lines of what you're looking for? You would still have to figure out which node belongs to which focus point though.

Comment: Yeah, a multi foci is what I'm going for, but I think the real problem is figuring out what gets taken to what focus point, since I imagine it would be more fluid and layout-dependent than just choosing an index and sticking to it. That's what stopped me from doing that from the start. Any pointers or examples you know of that show what I'm going for? I checked through quite a bit but I may have missed something.

Comment: Not aware of anything like that. Also it sounds like the force layout isn't suitable for this kind of thing.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Which component do you think would be best suited for something like this (just with these basic requirements)? I was really hoping to make this a d3 project.

Comment: You would need to implement custom forces. This can certainly be done in D3, but there's no ready-made layout for this.

Comment: That's fair. It would be similar to [this custom force layout](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1021841), maybe? At least, for learning how to do it. Is there a place I can read up on creating a custom force? My google-fu isn't giving me any meaningful results.

Comment: No, not similar to anything I've seen, but conceptually quite simple. All you need is to compute the attraction of the big nodes and change the velocity vector of the small nodes accordingly. Combine that with collision detection to prevent overlap. Not aware of any tutorials for creating custom forces.

Comment: Great. Thank you for your help so far, it's been fabulous! I'll give this a shot but I have no idea when I'll actually figure it out. I'll be sure to update this post when I get a solution though.